# efficiently grep strings between 2 patterns in LARGE log files

Tags: python, awk, sed, grep

I am trying to parse large log file by grep strings between 2 different patterns

example :

```
line1
line2
...
lineN
pattern1
line4
line6
pattern2
....
other lines
pattern1
line8
line9
pattern2
...
```

The lines I need to catch is the part between pattern1/pattern2 (so, `line4` through `line6` and `line8` through `line9`).

I am using

```
sed -n '/pattern1/,/pattern2/p
```

to search the file , but it takes really long time to complete (yeah, my log file is large ...)

I am wondering is there a more efficient way to speed up the search? 
Ideally a single line command (awk/grep etc...) or Python.

Comment: I doubt you'd find any solution with awk/python to be faster than `sed`.. you can use `LC_ALL=C sed -n '/pattern1/,/pattern2/p'` to speed up if input is all ASCII... see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/38978201/4082052 if you do not want the starting/ending lines in output

Comment: You could test if this is going a little faster: `sed -n '/^pattern1$/,/^pattern2$/p`

Comment: If the real patterns are static strings, it's not impossible that Awk with `$0 == "pattern1"` could be faster than `sed -n '/^pattern1$/` but in the grand scheme of things, I/O buffering overhead will massively dominate over and shadow any code performance differences.

Comment: I tried suggestions from Sundeep and Cyrus, no obvious speed up observed.

Comment: @Sundeep the links you offered does help, thank you !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select lines between two patterns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38972736/how-to-select-lines-between-two-patterns)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
awk '/pattern1/,/pattern2/'
```

In my experience `mawk` can be significantly faster than `sed` with this kind of operation and is usually the fastest. Alternatively `gawk4` can be much faster than `gawk3`, so you could try that too.

--edit--

FWIW, just did a small test on a file with 4 million lines

On MacOS 10.13:

```
sed  :         1.62 real         1.61 user         0.00 sys
gsed :         1.31 real         1.30 user         0.00 sys
awk  :         2.14 real         2.12 user         0.00 sys
gawk3:         5.05 real         3.90 user         1.13 sys
gawk4:         0.61 real         0.60 user         0.00 sys
mawk :         0.42 real         0.40 user         0.00 sys
```

On Centos 7.4:

```
gsed :         1.56 real         1.54 user         0.01 sys
gawk4:         1.31 real         1.29 user         0.01 sys
mawk :         0.56 real         0.54 user         0.01 sys
```

Comment: what if I want to print both pattern1 / pattern2 besides the strings in between ?

Comment: Use Scrutinizer's answer?

Comment: Like Cyrus says this answer includes both pattern1 and pattern2. Also added some test results...

Comment: yes, Cyrus and Scrutinizer , it does include pattern1/pattern2 (sorry, I made a mistake on my test so no pattern1/2 displayed) . As for cmd exec time , mine got obvious improvement when using "awk" command (Ubuntu16.6)
---- time using "sed -n '/pattern1/,/pattern2/p' " ----
real 7m14.025s
user 6m56.217s
sys 0m17.552s

--- time using " awk '/pattern1/,/pattern2/' " ----
real 1m46.925s
user 1m34.533s
sys 0m13.066s

Comment: @Jia, if `mawk` is not present on your system, you could try and install it (it should be available for Ubuntu), to see if it renders further improvements.

Comment: sure, I will try. thank you :)
One more question if you don't mind , do you know why awk is times faster than sed in this case ? Just curious , I am very new to sed and awk .

Answer (score 0):

You can try this if you use Python:

```
m = re.search(r'(?<=pattern1)(.|\s)*?(?=pattern2)', log_file, re.MULTILINE)
```

Comment: Louis, seems like I cannot match my expected strings out using this command , I am still trying to figure out, will let you know if I find working pattern using re module , thank you !